# Inserting a clickable image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to insert a clickable image, that is, if any part of the image is clicked, it will either act like a button element, or more preferably, run a Javascript script.

I was thinking of inserting an image into a button element, but as far as I can tell, that would NOT just make the whole image into a button, but rather insert it into a button box.

How do I make a clickable image, that pulls up a script?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this.

```
<img id="Img" src="img.jpg" />
```

Adding an onclick attribute:

```
<img id="Img" src="img.jpg" onclick="myFunction()" />
```

Adding onclick event listener from script:

```
document.getElementById( "Img" ).onclick = function() {
    // img clicked
};
```

Put image as button background

```
<input type="button" style="background: url( img.jpg )" />
```

Comment: should be `<img id="Img" src="img.jpg" onClick="myFunction()" />`. difference is `onClick` vs `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

the best way would be to use an onClick attribute or add an event listener, but i personally like to use the anchor tag:

```
<a href = "#" ><img src = "#" ></a>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).